# React: Pass 2 props back to the parent component in the same function from the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the state and close the modal at the same time, both are done by passing props back to the parent component. The problem I'm having is that only 1 seems to want to work at a time. I can get both working by themselves, but as soon as they're both there it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

```
CHILD COMPONENT

useSelectedImage = () => {
  this.props.saveChosenImage(this.state.imageChosen)
  this.props.closeModal();
};

<button onClick={this.useSelectedImage}>INSERT IMAGE</button>


PARENT COMPONENT

state = {
imageModalOpen: false,
}
// open the image modal
openImageModal = () => {
this.setState({ ...this.state, imageModalOpen: true })
};
// close the image modal
handleImageClose = () => {
this.setState({ ...this.state, imageModalOpen: false })
};

<Modal
  open={this.state.imageModalOpen}
  onClose={this.handleImageClose}
>
  <DialogContent className={classes.DialogContent}>
    <SelectImageModal saveChosenImage={this.saveChosenImage} closeModal={this.handleImageClose}/>
  </DialogContent>
<modal>

saveChosenImage = (image) => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, imageChosen: image })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this.

```
CHILD COMPONENT

useSelectedImage = () => {
   this.props.saveChosenImage(this.state.imageChosen);
-  this.props.closeModal();   //remove this
};
...

PARENT COMPONENT
...
saveChosenImage = (image) => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, imageChosen: image, imageModalOpen: false }); // modified here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call one function inside the other. This way you maintain the purity of your methods. You could still reuse `handleImageClose` on a close button without selecting an image.

See the example on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-torvalds-3dyv5

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Child = props => {
  const useSelectedImage = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    // DO THIS
    return props.closeModal(props.saveChosenImage(props.theImage));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={useSelectedImage}>Select Image</button>
      <button onClick={props.closeModal}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class Parent extends Component {
  openImageModal = () => console.log("OPEN FIRED");

  handleImageClose = () => {
    console.log("CLOSED FIRED");
    this.setState({ closed: true });
  };

  saveChosenImage = image => {
    console.log(`SAVED!! ${image}`);
    this.setState({ image });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <Child
        saveChosenImage={this.saveChosenImage}
        closeModal={this.handleImageClose}
        theImage="cow.jpg"
      />
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```